# Angular service updates variable but view doesn't update

Tags: angularjs

Here is a jsfiddle of my issue.  http://jsfiddle.net/angularismyman/pc5tq0wa/ Basically my controller 2 is calling a service which is updating a variable my controller 1's view is binded to, but the view isn't updating.

My Html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        Controller 1: <br/>
        {{text}}
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
        Controller 2: <br/>
        <button ng-click="updateView()">Change text in controller 1 to Jelly</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My service and both controllers:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('Session', function () {

    var value = "peanut butter";

    this.value = value;

    this.changeTest = function(){
        alert("changing to jelly!");
        alert("our current value is: "+value);
        value = "jelly";
        alert("our new value is: "+value);
        alert("why isn't text updating in controller 1?");
    }

    return this
});

function FirstCtrl($scope, Session){
  $scope.text = Session.value;
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, Session){
    $scope.updateView = function(){
        Session.changeTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/XP3BMk?p=preview 1) `this.value = value;` you are copying the string value from one variable to another property. 2)`value = "jelly"` does not affect `this.value` they are completely different. 3) `Session.value` is just a string value and not any reference `$scope.text` will just hold the value it was set with intially.

Comment: You can either write a function to return the value from the service, or access the value via the session object's property. http://jsfiddle.net/pc5tq0wa/1/

Comment: Thanks guys this solved it.  Should I answer this question myself because these are just comments?  If you answer I'll accept and upvote.

Comment: @That1guyoverthr Provide the answer yourself.